# TeeChart TLegendScrollBar visual issue when clicking on scroll-arrow

Tags: teechart, c++builder-xe5

IDE: `c++ Builder XE5 Update 2`

TeeChart: `TeeChart Pro 2014.11.140512 VCL/FMX release`

I utilized TeeChart's `TLegendScrollBar` tool for the first time recently(handy tool).
The issue I have come across:

When clicking on one of the scroll-arrows the following happens:

1. **Single Click** - The owner chart's `TChart.Color` property changes(background color). The original color is then restored once another event updates the chart.
2. **Hold Down** - The owner chart's `TChart.Color` property *randomly* toggles between the original color and unwanted color.

The color changes seems to happen after a `TChart.OnAfterDraw` call(after the intial `OnAfterClick` call for the **Single Click** case).

Example(Before and After):

[image: Before and After]

Easy to replicate:

1. Create new VCL Forms application and add a `TChart` component to the form.
2. Add a `TLegendScrollBar` tool and number of series to the chart(chart editor).
3. Set the `TChart.Legend.MaxNumRows` property to a value smaller than `TChart.SeriesCount()`.
4. Run.

**Questions**:

1. Is there a entry point(s) after `TChart.OnAfterDraw` wherein I could attempt to rectify the issue? Or a workaround?
2. (if not **1**) Is there a way to completely *remove*(hide and disable) the scroll arrows?(force the user to use either the mouse-wheel or scroll-thumb to scroll the legend)

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce the problem so I've added it to the public tracker: [B979](http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=979)
You can follow the ticket to get automatic notifications when an update arrives.